# Recamán Sequence (A005132)

Tags: clojure

I'm going to screw around with visualizing [Recamán's Sequence](http://oeis.org/A005132), but want to have a good sequence generator to generate the sequence before I start. I want to use a lazy generator for my actual application, but decided to make a strict version first since it will likely be simpler.

This is what I ended up with. It works (verified against the OEIS), but is *quite* verbose. I don't *technically* require `seen`, but doing constant linear searching over `acc` would likely be unacceptable. I'm just looking for broad suggestions on how this can be improved, because while it's fairly fast (it can find the first million numbers in ~2 seconds on my potato), it's rather ugly.

I know though that I can make use of transients here, but they're easy enough to add afterwards that that's not a big deal.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, because I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

```
(defn strict-recamans-sequence [max-n]
  (let [c-last #(get % (dec (count %)))]
    (loop [n 1
           seen #{}
           acc [0]]
      (if (> n max-n)
        acc

        (let [prev (c-last acc)
              back (- prev n)
              new-n (if (and (pos? back) (not (seen back)))
                      back
                      (+ prev n))]
          (recur (inc n) (conj seen new-n) (conj acc new-n)))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I like the implementation of `c-last` as it produces an `O(1)` runtime with vectors (instead using the `last` function with `O(n)` runtime)
- However, you do not need `c-last` as you could also keep track of the last value in the `loop` bindings.
- If you do not need to eagerly compute the numbers in a vector, you can also use [lazy sequences](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/lazy-seq). It is not too difficult to write something in a lazy manner if you can already write it recursively.
- When replacing a `loop` with a recursive function call you can pass the loop's bindings as function parameters.

The result would look something like this.

```
(defn recaman []
  (letfn [(tail [previous n seen]
            (let [nx (if (and (> previous n) (not (seen (- previous n))))
                       (- previous n)
                       (+ previous n))]
              (cons nx (lazy-seq (tail nx (inc n) (conj seen nx))))))]
    (tail 0 0 #{})))
```

Calling `(receman)` will produce an infinite lazy sequence.

```
(take 100 (recaman))
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not great at writing lazy functions, so this is a big help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a lazy sequence, this may be a good example of [using Python-style generator functions](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#generator-functions-for-lazy-sequences-a-la-python).  An example:

```
(defn concat-gen    ; concat a list of collections
  [& collections]
  (lazy-gen
    (doseq [curr-coll collections]
      (doseq [item curr-coll]
        (yield item)))))

(defn concat-gen-pair
  [& collections]
  (lazy-gen
    (doseq [curr-coll collections]
      (doseq [item curr-coll]
        (yield-all [item item])))))

(def c1 [1 2 3])
(def c2 [4 5 6])
(def c3 [7 8 9])

(is= [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]                            (concat-gen       c1 c2 c3))
(is= [1 1  2 2  3 3  4 4  5 5  6 6  7 7  8 8  9 9]  (concat-gen-pair  c1 c2 c3))
```